# IPV6 address assigned to only one of the interfaces of an EPC(Evolved Packet Core) module not to other interfaces

Tags: c, linux, lte, 3gp, ims

When I am assigning IP addresses to the interfaces mgmt, net_a & net_b of an EPC(Evolved Packet Core) modules like sgw or pgw. It assigns IPV6 address i.e. inet6 addr only to one of the net_a interface & not to other interfaces. In the screen shot here its clearly visible that inet6 or IPV6 address is only assigned to the net_a interface and not to net_b or mgmt interface.

[image]

Here in the screenshot its visible that when I run the script of one of the modules of EPC it cannot bind IPV6 socket & is unable to assign the requested address due to which after 30 attempts of IP binding it throws Segmentation fault error. Is this because some of the interfaces are not assigned IPV6 addresses?

[image]

Comment: Does this have anything to do with c code?

Comment: In the second image you have attached i can see that there is some IPV6 address: ''FC00:1234:2::10" . I think your C program trying to use this address to bind, which is not the address of any interface on your system that's why it's unable to assign. Can you please replace this address with some correct IPV6 address here and try again. Please let me know if you did not get your problem correctly.